# Replace all urls as links in PHP

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-match-all

I want to make all the urls in a text as hyperlinks. I have done the following. But the links are missing with ':'. Any help appreciated.

```
<?php

$string = "Hallo Studenten http://google.com/your/subpage and https://www.yahoo.com/my/subpage";
  $regexp = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
  $anchorMarkup = "<a href=\"%s://%s\" target=\"_blank\" >%s</a>";

  preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches, \PREG_SET_ORDER);

  foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (empty($match[1]) && empty($match[7])) {
      $http = $match[2]?$match[2]:'http';
      $replace = sprintf($anchorMarkup, $http, $match[0], $match[0], $match[1]);
      $string = str_replace($match[0], $replace, $string);
    }
  }
  echo $string; 
?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2yg5-i3uj

Comment: First do a dump of `$matches`, you don't have any capture group.

Comment: Where the links are missing with ':'?

Comment: @questlooking ':' is missing in the 'href' of output.

Comment: Your pattern problem aside, you're doing it the wrong way. Forget `preg_match_all` + `sprintf` + `str_replace` and use `preg_replace_callback` with capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$string       = "Hallo Studenten http://google.com/your/subpage and https://www.yahoo.com/my/subpage";
$regexp       = "/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i";
$anchorMarkup = "<a href=\"$0\" target=\"_blank\" >$0</a>";

echo preg_replace($regexp, $anchorMarkup, $string);
```